# Image Transition example: How to do them in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am curious as what you would call the image transitions in this wp template demo?

http://themes.muffingroup.com/tisson/

I would like to learn how to do those but I don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: http://wowslider.com/slideshow-software-zoom-domino-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is REVOLUTION SLIDER 2.3.91 (got it from its code).

These links will help you install this wp plugin

http://www.orbis-ingenieria.com/code/documentation/documentation.html#!/documenter_cover

&

http://magique-docs.cmsmasters.net/revolution-slider-setup/

And here is the original documentation of this

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/revolution-slider-a-premium-drag-and-drop-slider-for-wordpress/

Hope it helps..!

Comment: Actually I know the plugin, my inquiry is about how did they make it. What materials should read so that I can make something similar.